# Why am I unable to access a web-site from my laptop to the virtual machine?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, apache-http-server

I have the apache web server on the virtual machine inside my laptop. Its local IP address is 169.254.196.186. The VM has two adapters: 1. NAT, 2. Bridge Adapter.

I can access the web page inside the VM using http://localhost:80 or  http://169.254.196.186:80. However, I cannot access the same web page from my laptop.

Also, when I query the IP address using **`ipconfig`** from my laptop, I don't see that particular IP address of the VM.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you running `ipconfig` inside the VM or directly on the host OS?

Comment: @user1686, both.

Answer (score 0):

> Its local IP address is 169.254.196.186.  The VM has two adapters: 1.
> NAT, 2. Bridge Adapter.

169.254.196.186 is the No DHCP address (no connection) and that is why no Internet.

Reduce to 1 Network Connection.  NAT should work fine.  Make sure that is your only connection.

You can also use Bridged Networking and that will put your VM on your router.

Make sure your VM NIC is properly set up as well.

Then restart the machine and check.

I am in a VM now with a NAT connection (just 1 network connection) and it works fine.

If for some reason you need 2 NIC's inside the VM, you may be better off with a bare metal Hypervisor.  That is down the road when you have more experience with this.

Use this guide to change (not add) NAT mode to Bridged mode.

[VBOX change to Bridged mode](https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/a-pretty-good-introduction-to-virtualbox-bridged-networking-mode#:%7E:text=Change%20Networking%20Mode%20to%20Bridged&text=Click%20the%20Network%20tab%20on,button%20to%20save%20your%20settings.)

Comment: How will my laptop find the VM without a bridge?

Comment: You can change to Bridged Networking to put your VM on your router. I added that to my answer. But do not try 2 NIC's inside your Virtual Box VM.

Comment: *Reduce to 1 Network Connection. NAT should work fine. Make sure that is your only connection.* --- How will my laptop find the VM in this case?

Comment: With 1 NIC you can use either method. I have done so. Both can work, just not simultaneously.

Comment: You can use 2 NIC's with a bare metal Hypervisor (which I noted) but that is much more complicated.

Comment: In my modified setting, I am using a VM with a NAT card. Now, when I type ipconfig on my laptop, I get 192.168.56.1. However, I cannot access the web-pages.

Comment: Try Bridged then, so it is easier to see from outside the VM.  You at least have a NIC connection now instead of No DHCP.

Comment: I added a bridge. Inside VB, ipconfig gives 169.254.4.5. In the laptop, ipconfig gives 192.168.56.1. Neither of them is accessible from the laptop.

Comment: Just change from NAT to Bridged. Do no use two

Comment: Now, I am using only one bridge, no NAT. Inside VM, I get the WiFi IP, no private IP. From the laptop, I get 192.168.56.1.    Neither from the laptop nor from inside VM is this IP accessible. Also, there is no Internet access in the VM.

Comment: Is your router 192.168.56.x?   Most people would not use such a router subnet.

Comment: Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f592:28f5:3ab0:430d%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Comment: If your router is not using 56 as subnet then you are still on NAT

Comment: I added a guide for changing from NAT to Bridged mode inside a guest machine.